# Can we clone a code and separate them with number in certain position?

Tags: webautomation, kantu

I'm using UI Vision and trying to make loop code. This is the main code:

```
{
  "Command": "click",
  "Target": "xpath=//*[@id=\"XXXXX\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/section/article[2]/button",
  "Value": "",
  "Targets": [
    "xpath=//*[@id=\"XXXXX\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/section/article[2]/button",
    "xpath=//article[2]/button",
    "css=#XXXXX > div > div.profile-detail-right-panel > div > div.sidebar-panels > div.panel-container.requireLogin.selected > div > div.scroller.is-scrollable.scroll-content.scroll-scrolly_visible > div > div.profile-user-list-container > section > article:nth-child(5) > button"
  ],
  "Description": ""
}
```

There is `XXXX/article[2]` which means it's the 2nd loop.

My questions is, is there any fastest way to clone that code until 100x loops or until `XXXX/article[100]` ?

Thank you. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your Qt (Question) has nothing to do with the [tag:imacros] Tag, this is annoying for (Advanced) Users watching/answering this Tag... (=> Can you remove it...!?) // For Qt's about `UI Vision`, => use the [tag:kantu] Tag (was the older Name for `UI Vision`). // And you have some "generic" [tag:webautomation] Tag for when you don't know/can't find the "proper" Tag(s). // The [tag:macros] is also rather irrelevant for this Thread...

Comment: OK good..., and hum, some Advanced User in the [tag:kantu] Tag (or with "enough" Rep) should create/propose a `ui-vision` Tag (which doesn't seem to exist (yet)), or maybe as a Synonym for the `kantu` Tag... :idea: